# Unable convert the data time of this column (object to time)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I have a data frame data types like below

```
    usr_id  year
0   t961    00:50:03.158000
1   t964    03:25:57
2   t335    00:55:00
3   t829    00:04:25.714000


usr_id    object
year      object
dtype: object
```

I want to convert the year column data type to a datetime. I used the below code.

```
timefmt = "%H:%M"
test['year'] = pd.to_datetime(
    test['year'], format=timefmt, errors='coerce').dt.time
```

I get below output

```
    usr_id  year
0   t961    NaT
1   t964    NaT
2   t335    NaT
3   t829    NaT
```

How can I convert the data time of this column (object to datetime)? 
How can I drop seconds & microseconds?

> Expected output

```
    usr_id   year
0   t961    00:50
1   t964    03:25
2   t335    00:55
3   t829    00:04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
timefmt = "%H:%M"
test['year'] = pd.to_datetime(test['year'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime(timefmt)

print (test)
  usr_id   year
0   t961  00:50
1   t964  03:25
2   t335  00:55
3   t829  00:04
```

Or you can use [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1` for split by last `:` and select first lists by indexing:

```
test['year'] = test['year'].str.rsplit(':', n=1).str[0]
print (test)
  usr_id   year
0   t961  00:50
1   t964  03:25
2   t335  00:55
3   t829  00:04
```

Or solution by @Akira:

```
test['year'] = test['year'].astype(str).str[:5]
```

Comment: ```test['year'] = test['year'].astype(str).str[0:5] ``` also get same output

Answer (score 0):

As there is currently no actual date in your `year` column, you need to set a default one. Then you you can pass a format to pandas `to_datetime` function.

This could be done in a one-liner like this:

```
test['year'] = pd.to_datetime(test['year'].apply(lambda x: '1900-01-01 '+ x),format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```